# Removing rows from data frames with multiple conditions using a loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame that currently looks like this:

```
     ID    Freq
     A     10
     B     
     A
     G     6
     B     11
     C     6
     C     7
     D     
     E
```

The data frame that I am after is this:

```
     ID    Freq
     A     10
     G     6
     B     11
     C     6
     C     7
     D     
     E
```

I am currently trying to write a loop that identifies duplicates in the `ID` column and then removes the duplicate row with the blank `Freq` value. If there are duplicate `ID`s where both have values in `Freq`, I don't want to delete them. Where do I begin with this? Would I use the `duplicated` function to identify the duplicates?

**EDIT:** Edited to add some rows to show that I want to retain a blank Freq value if the ID is not a duplicate.

Comment: It seems like identifying the duplicates doesn't really matter here, it's all about whether `Freq` is blank or not.

Comment: @jaap sorry - I've just edited the question and added in more rows. I want still want to retain blank Freqs so  long as the ID is not a duplicate

Comment: @RonakShah sorry - I've just edited the question and added in more rows. I want still want to retain blank Freqs so long as the ID is not a duplicate

Comment: @Marius sorry - I've just edited the question and added in more rows. I want still want to retain blank Freqs so long as the ID is not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `group_by` `ID` and `filter` groups only where there are more than 1 row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(if(n() > 1) Freq != "" else TRUE)

#  ID    Freq 
#  <fct> <chr>
#1 A     10   
#2 G     6    
#3 B     11   
#4 C     6    
#5 C     7    
#6 D     ""   
#7 E     ""
```

In base R, we can use `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(Freq != "", ID, FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1) x else TRUE))
```

---

For the updated request we can add a check for blank values to select only one of them.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(if(n() > 1) Freq != "" | !duplicated(Freq == "") else TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah ! To further complicate things, how can I edit the code so that if there are duplicate rows of ID "F" but both have blanks in the Freq column, also only delete one of those rows, rather than both?

Comment: @Dieu94 and if there are three blank rows of ID "F" how many you would delete and how many you would keep ?

Comment: Just one row - regardless of how many duplicates there  are of F.

Comment: Yes-  perfect, thank you! Could you explain to me what the last line in the code means?

Comment: @Dieu94 in each group if there is more than 1 row, it selects rows which is not empty OR which are empty and but not duplicated (meaning the first empty row out of all empty rows) else if there is only one row in group it selects that row by default.